# Cannot import numpy with python3.5, but can import with python2.7

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy

I can use numpy with built in python. But with python3.5 interpreter, it says

`ImportError: No module named 'numpy'`

but when I type `$ sudo pip3 install numpy` it says

```
"Requirement already satisfied: numpy in /root/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages"
```

What should I do?

Comment: can you please precise your question you are trying your code in python3.5 and sitepackage location at python3.6??

Comment: however if you still face problem then check if your python path is in system environment or not.

Answer (score 1):

I had the similar problems before. When you run `pip3`, it actually linked to pip in your python3.6. Packages for different python distributions are in different folders. `python3.5 -m pip install numpy` should solve the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Install module to python3.5 with `pip3.5 install numpy` or user python3.6 interpreter.

Comment: `no distributions at all found for numpy`